# WPF: Get an item's position index within CollectionViewSource and not on the bound source

Tags: wpf, collectionviewsource

I've got a view model that exposes a CollectionViewSource built around my observable collection. I also have a command for deleting items:

```
public ObservableCollection<FooViewModel> Foos { get; set; }
public ICollectionView FooCollectionView { get; set; }
public ICommand DeleteFooCommand { get; set; }

private FooViewModel _SelectedFoo;
public FooViewModel SelectedFoo
{
    get { return _SelectedFoo; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _SelectedFoo)
        {
            _SelectedFoo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public MyViewModel()
{
    Foos = new ObservableCollection<FooViewModel>();
    FooCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Patches);
    FooCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    DeleteFooCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteFoo);
}

private void DeleteFoo(object parameter)
{
    var collection = parameter as IEnumerable;
    if (collection == null) return;

    var itemsToDelete = collection.OfType<FooViewModel>().ToList();
    if (!itemsToDelete.Any()) return;

    SelectedFoo = null;

    // TODO: Figure out what the next SelectedFoo should be after deleting) 

    foreach (var item in itemsToDelete)
        Foos.Remove(item);
}
```

In the spirit of MVVM, I don't want to know whether or not my CollectionViewSource was bound to a ListBox, ListView, etc. I simply expect one or more FooViewModels in my command parameter (via [control].SelectedItems). However, I want to set the new SelectedFoo to what I think would be the next logical item that should be selected. I know there is IndexOf() of my source collection, but that index won't match the index after the sort of my CollectionViewSource. Is there a way to get the index of the item on the view and not the source? I can do what I want if I pass the bound ListBox as my command parameter, but I'd rather not know about the bound control.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly (i.e. how to obtain the resulting index of an item in a collection view) - you can take advantage of the fact that the collection view enumerates the items in sorted order and then simply utilize ***Linq*** to count items preceding the one you're interested in. Since I'm not sure how to mix it into your view-model (*you're not even checking if currently selected item is among the deleted ones?*), here's an extension method that will return the resulting index of an item in a collection view:

```
public static int IndexOf(this ICollectionView view, object item)
{
    return view.Cast<object>().TakeWhile(x => !Equals(x, item)).Count();
}
```

Note though that this solution is not universal because it assumes that `item` is both in the source collection **and** is not filtered out by the collection view. Otherwise it will return the total count of items in the view (excluding the filtered ones). A universal solution would go something like this:

```
public static int IndexOf(this ICollectionView view, object item)
{
    var e = view.GetEnumerator();
    var idx = 0;
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        if (Equals(item, e.Current))
            return idx;
        else
            idx++;
    }
    //if we've got this far it means that the item is either filtered out
    //or is not in the source collection
    return -1;
}
```

Then of course there's another problem, namely you cannot access items by index in a collection view. So you have to enumerate the collection second time:

```
var idx = view.IndexOf(item);
var nextItem = view.Cast<object>().ElementAtOrDefault(idx + 1);
```

That should not be a problem for fairly small collections, but may become one for large collections (remember that the view enumerates items in **sorted** order, so unless the sorting result is cached, each enumeration would require to sort the whole collection).

To answer a slightly modified question (*"How do I get an item following a particular one from a sorted collection view?"*) there's a simple solution that needs to enumerate the collection only once:

```
var nextItem = view.Cast<object>()
    .SkipWhile(x => !Equals(x, item)) //skip preceding items
    .Skip(1) //skip the item itself
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that this will return `null` if the item is not present in the resulting collection or is its last item.

Comment: But what if you need to find next item after **multiple** deleted items? Your solution is really nice but works for one deleted item only. Also it is not good to use `object` since you can use `Cast` or `OfType` with specific type.

Comment: @Maxim Then it depends on what exactly do you mean by "next item after multiple deleted items". As for casting to `object` - I tried to abstract the problem and solution form OP's example so using for example `FooViewModel` would imply a lot of assumptions (e.g. that `FooViewModel` is a reference type and not a value type).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static int IndexOf<TItem>(this ICollectionView collectionView, TItem item)
{
    int result = 0;

    foreach (var i in collectionView.OfType<TItem>())
    {
        if (i == item)
            return result;

        result++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This solution is correct provided that **a)** the source collection only contains instances of `TItem` (does not contain `null`s or objects of other type) and **b)** the `==` operator is not overloaded for `TItem` (or is equivalent to default `IEqualityComparer<TItem>`).